# Suggestion for question on: "VIF, Condition Index and eigen values"

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

The question on: [VIF, Condition Index and eigen values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4099/28) has been closed as off-topic. I disagree with that decision. While I agree with some of the comments that the question can be improved the question itself is on-topic. I also agree that the OP in question has not demonstrated sufficient involvement (via voting) but do note that the OP has awarded rep by accepting an answer on one question.

I suggest the following resolution to the issue:

1. Merge the unregistered, registered user ids of the OP. (Can a mod please help the OP here?)
2. The OP or a moderator deletes the 'answer' posted on the question seeking help as that should be on meta as pointed out by whuber. Perhaps, the OP does not know about meta?
3. Once the OP's account issue is resolved and the OP votes up questions as appropriate, the question is opened up.

Once the above three steps have taken place, in the interest of a maximizing a clean site, perhaps most of the comments that are no longer relevant can be deleted?

Summary: Closing this question which is on-topic is not a resolution to the issue we have been having.

Any thoughts on the above suggestions?

**Edit**

I am giving below the history of comments for this question for posterity as we should delete those comments as the issue is nearly resolved:

@ayush At least, you should keep in mind that those that previously answered your questions are probably expecting a check from you about the usefulness of their answers to your questions. – chl Nov 1 at 10:27

@chl..I have already checked many of those..including yours and non-stop. Please see it again..I know I am late but as I said earlier I was new to this community and still new. Having said that, I pledge to vote or tick for the answers I find useful. – ayush biyani Nov 1 at 11:02
3   up voted
@ayush What you call "many" actually stands for one accepted answer and no upvote. Anyway, the purpose of my comments was mainly that you should consider writing clear questions (they are interesting on their own), with one definitive issue, and reserve comments for additional infos relevant to your original question, not follow-up. BTW, "non-stop" should actually read @onestop. Let's stop that, this is definitely not the purpose of this SE, and I have no doubt about your willingness and enthusiasm to contribute to it. – chl Nov 1 at 11:37

@chl finally I get a good comment..anyway I am wondering nobody's answering my recent question.. – ayush biyani Nov 1 at 11:46

@ayush I suspect that @chl (and others) are gently trying to get you involved in more than asking questions on this site. That you haven't upvoted a single question suggests a lack of interest in this site or its subject matter. (This is characteristic of people fishing for answers to homework problems, for example.) Your contributions in the form of answers to other questions, voting on questions and responses (including responses to your own questions!), and comments would be valuable and welcome. – whuber Nov 1 at 15:04

@whuber- I reiterate that I didnt know people vote(up and down) to people's answers. Frankly speaking now this is getting lil naging..I assure every people reading this post that I am more than just fishing for my answers in this site. People who are experienced in this site can kindly ask themselves this question as to how much did they contribute in their hey days in this site and you'd get some answers. Again...lets stop this thing and concentrate on statistics than each person repeating the same thing..sorry if I sound harsh but now this is getting over my last nerve... – ayush biyani Nov 2 at 7:04

@chl- Can you please vouch for my interest in this site as you did in one of other's comments. I guess then whuber would take your word and leave me with clothes. – ayush biyani Nov 2 at 7:07
2   up voted
@ayush No nagging here. The repetition is warranted by your failure to change your behavior. Insinuations about other participants and their alleged histories with this site are neither appropriate nor constructive. Just read the FAQ, please; act accordingly; and nobody will bother you again about these issues. As I wrote earlier, you are warmly welcome on this site and I look forward to your active and productive participation. – whuber 2 days ago

@whuber-- I respect your immense experience in the field of stats and with this site..But it seems that you havent read my full comment..you answered about the nagging part but you didnt answer the part which asks everyone how much did you contribute in the first 5 days of your membership ? and now since you have pointed out my failure to change my behavior can you please see the number of posts i have ticked and upvoted..that since I got the first comment from chl..I know alleged history of other participants are not constructive but u have to keep in mind before saying me again and again. – ayush biyani 2 days ago

@whuber as I said earlier as well lets concentrate on the activities rather than digging the old potholes..I think our energy is getting diverted into something else.. – ayush biyani 2 days ago

@ayush I'm afraid to say that you are misinterpreting our advices. I'm very keen to contribute to the development of this SE, not to waste my time trying to explain the FAQ or justifying every of my words. We all agree that your contribution on this Q&A is welcome, which means that we expect you to be involved in asking questions and providing responses, and voting in both cases. It may be that the responses you ticked were not recorded, because actually you still have 0 votes. Expecting a response from specific people in this SE is not encouraged since everybody can participate. – chl 2 days ago

@chl I am very sure site is not recording it though why would it happen to me alone..anwyay..lets play our best shot. I assure you that I will not interpret your advice wrong way. – ayush biyani 2 days ago
@whuber @chl @ayush I may be mistaken but it seems that unregistered users cannot vote. So, perhaps, the answer to the problem is for ayush to register. – Srikant Vadali yesterday 
3

@ayush You have zero votes and now three questions. The simple request from others involved here is to vote on answers to your existing questions. Period. Regarding this current question: it could also be improved because it's asked many different questions without a clear common thread. Are you interested in multicollinearity in general? Or are you interested in VIF? It would be better to break these out for clarity. – Shane♦ yesterday

@Srikant-vadali But @ayush must be registered since he has rep. – csgillespie♦ yesterday
@csgillespie Nope. See his user profile. Apparently, you can get rep even if you are unregistered or so a cursory meta.SO search shows. I do not know how current my info is or if things have changed recently. – Srikant Vadali yesterday

@csgillespie Isn't this user registered? He has a name. Non-registered users are something like user123412512... – Shane♦ yesterday
@shane I just now noticed that this user has two accounts. One registered and the other not. For some reason, the registered account did not show up earlier in the day. – Srikant Vadali yesterday

Comment: I have merged his accounts.

Comment: @mbq Thanks. I had to leave just before Srikant asked me to.

Comment: @mbq Thanks. @ayush @whuber @chl @shane: FYI- I see that the OP of the original question has now upvoted questions/answers and is participating as appropriate. Can the comments reg voting/contributing be deleted to clean up that question? I have deleted mine and voted to re-open the question.

Comment: @Skrikant Yes, the OP is now asking, commenting, and voting with his new merged account, which is very cool. You can delete my comments. Thanks to all of you for acting so promptly and help solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that closing the question wasn't ideal, but it seemed like we would have another page worth of comments. And when comments weren't enough we would start to get responses as [answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4099/vif-condition-index-and-eigen-values/4207#4207). The question was also starting to get flagged by users.

In my opinion, if the OP sorts out his voting/registration we can delete the comments and reopen the question.

Basically I see closing this question as *putting the question on hold*.

**EDIT**

I just noticed that I didn't actually address your proposal. I agree with your three points above.

**Update 2**

I've deleted the comments and reopened the question. Thanks to @Srikant-Vadali for coordinating this.

Comment: It might be possible that a registered account with 1 rep cannot comment on a question that was posted by the unregistered account. This may explain the 'answer'. Can you merge the accounts so that we do not have two accounts for this user?

Answer (score 3):

I am happy to see the question closed, not because it is off-topic but because the associated comments that have been left are going to be a little bit off-topic themselves.

I initially flagged the question, just because I thought someone else should act as a "moderator". Anyway, it seems the OP wasn't aware of the voting system, then wasn't able to vote because of his duplicated account or something like that. Myself, I'm not familiar with SEs, and I don't like judging an user about his/her behavior. Anyway, even without reading the FAQ, I think the principle of voting and/or accepting answer is not so outstanding... But more importantly, I was originally trying to suggest to this particular user that it is not very appropriate to use comments as a way to ask further questions ([Understanding AIC and Schwarz criterion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3984/aic-and-sc-value/), and [How to perform t-test with huge samples?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/how-to-perform-t-test-with-huge-samples/)); in the meantime, I realized that he didn't vote at all.

Clearly, the question is on-topic, but there's too much confusion around that question now. So it is better to start another question, and delete this one. I think everyone, including the OP, will agree with that proposition.

Comment: I also found the question itself to be rambling; it required more clarification and possibly should have been split into several questions.

Comment: @Shane Yes, I agree (esp. the title includes "eigen values"...) and also suggested to rework it a little. But, then we exchanged a lot of comments that are not that appropriate on a Q&A website (IMO).

Comment: Deleting the original question with a request to repost to the OP and merging of the OP's two accounts also seems to be a good option.

Comment: @Srikant I fully agree with that proposition.

Comment: He claims to have voted, but obviously not from the profile.  Maybe he doesn't really understand the site or he's got an old browser that doesn't handle javascript/ajax as nicely?

Comment: Hmm, just noticed he accepted an answer, so something must be working.  Not sure if he's being difficult or just doesn't understand voting.

Comment: @ars My meta.SO search shows that unregistered voters can accept but not vote which may explain what you see. However, this may have changed recently.

Comment: @Srikant: oh, you're right.  I guess the 56-rep and 1-rep accounts are confusing things.  Hopefully @ayush will visit this thread so we can help him sort it out.  Agree with your proposals, btw.